# Windows can't install network adapter on Hyper-V Guest Win10

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v

I have a windows 10 vm created from a failing SSD using sysinternals disk2vhd. I have created a new Gen2 Hyper-V virtual machine using the vhdx. I have installed a virtual adapter connected to an external virtual switch. Within the guest, the device manager shows the network adapter in error state with Windows is still setting up the class configuration for this device. (Code 56).

Within the guest, I have tried uninstalling all VPN software and disabling any services for software that I cannot uninstall (e.g. VMWare Player, which was installed on a now unreachable external drive). I have tried to remove the hyper-v role for the guest, but windows will not allow it (using both the windows features and DISM). I have run sfc /scannow. I have tried a network reset.

There are now no adapters showing in the network configuration, and in fact Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} shows only the default MS Kernel debug, wan miniport (hidden in device manager), and the failed MS Hyper-V network adapter. Under Network Properties, I can still see all the definitions of the former adapters, but they are all listed as status = Not Present.

I have searched the web and this site for similar problems, but no solutions work. Any attempt to hot add virtual adapters (internal, default, external) all produce a device with the code 56 error. I would have thought that Network Reset was the nuclear option, but it clearly cannot remove whatever conflicting driver software is present.

My question: is there somewhere I can look in the registry or on the hard drive to find lingering conflicting software? How would I go about finding this (event viewer application/system logs are no help)?

Comment: Have you tried an inplace-upgrade of your Windows 10? Code 56 means the driver for the device can't work with the Operating Sysem, or maybe conflicting and is incompatible. __"Resetting your network really should be used as a last resort in your troubleshooting process."__ https://www.howtogeek.com/265870/how-to-reset-your-entire-network-in-windows-10-and-start-from-scratch/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but even if I could somehow get the ISO to the guest, I don't have the space required to duplicate the windows folder. It's frustrating that I can't just reinstall the networking components. And believe me, I'm at last resorts.

Comment: As stated in the link below, driver reinstallation should fix the issue.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/code-56-in-device-manager-wireless-lan-after-using/e73eaf07-2d44-4ade-aa23-4176c060f6ed
Another option, you can try installing integration tools on your VM. The last resort would be trying other P2V tools to create VM. StarWind V2V as an example. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter
I would recommend you creating image of your SSD, just in case it will die, you will still have image of your OS.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I found the current drivers for the PCIe network adapter using my Dell service tag. I copied the exe to the desktop of the VM and executed. Drivers installed correctly. Rebooted, removed and re-add the external switch virtual adapter, but no luck, still stuck at code 56. Enabled various integration tools, no change. I think this conflict goes pretty deep and given the constraints I have, I'm not able to reinstall windows.